# SharepointOnlineCredentials not working in an app

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, wcf, odata

I want to authenticate against sharepoint online site using SharepointOnlineCredentials class. Below code works fine in a console application. But the same code is generating error when written in wcf data service and consumed in a provider hosted app.

```
  ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("<Sharepoint online site url>");
  SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
  foreach (char c in _password)
  {
      securePassword.AppendChar(c);
  }
  //Generates exception on this step. Exception details provided below
  SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_username, securePassword);
  clientContext.Credentials = creds;
```

> **Exception Details:**
>
> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.CheckHResult(Int32 hr) 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.EnsureInited()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.LogonIdentity(String
>   username, SecureString password)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.Logon(String
>   username, SecureString password)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials..ctor(String
>   username, SecureString password)

Answer (score 1):

The way the SharePointOnlineCredentials must be used differ from a client app versus web service - i believe this example explains it http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2013/03/18/connecting-to-office-365-using-client-side-object-model-and-web-services/

Comment: I visited the link and tried what he has suggested.. but it does not solve my problem.